# Is there a way to turn a Button in GridView to a link text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

The size of the button really kills the width of my GridView and so I am looking to just change the buttons into a link (like if you were to use AutoGenerateEditButton or AutoGenerateDeleteButton). Here's what I have:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="editButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" 
            Text="Edit"  />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="BtnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" 
            Text="Edit" />
        <asp:Button ID="BtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
            Text="Cancel" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

How would I change what I have into just a text that is like a link (once again, like if it was from AutoGenerateEditButton). I can't set that to true because I need to conditionally hide it and I can't seem to do it if it's automatically generated. If you know a way to conditionally hide it when it's automatically generated, please let me know!

Take note that I'm using a SQLDataSource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `LinkButton` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="editButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <div style="white-space: nowrap;">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed. Is there a way to make them inline with each other in the column? Once you click "Edit", "Edit" is on top of "Cancel" and vice versa.

Comment: You could wrap it in a div and do `white-space: nowrap;` and see if that does it. I tweaked the answer. If that doesn't work, you can manually set the width to accommodate them.

Comment: Now I'm aware of the existence of a `LinkButton`. Thanks! Marked as best.